# HAXM not installed

Tags: android-studio, haxm

[SDK Manager Setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zJRQJ.png)on SDK Manager  Intel x86 Emulater Accelerater  (HAXM Installer ) 7.6.5 Installed ,
but when I launch AVD on emulator i get error

**Intel HAXM is required to run this AVD.
HAXM not installed.**
[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YZtn6.png)

Comment: Try installing the newest haxm - HAXM v7.7.0 at https://github.com/intel/haxm/releases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes the case is that you dont have Haxm install on your pc. you can easily download it from the website.You can go this link in which I have explained
[https://youtu.be/ReLBzK2yJow[](https://youtu.be/ReLBzK2yJow%5B) HAXM installation ][1]

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).